# Обработчик

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте мне надо узнать добавлен ли пользователь в друзья или нет? 
**P.S.** все добавления в друзья добавляются в базу.

Вот дамп:

```
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, //id добавлений
  `idUser` varchar(11) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, //мой id
  `idUserFriend` varchar(11) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, //id которого я добавил
  `avatarUser` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, //мой аватар
  `loginUser` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, //мой логин
  `loginUserFriend` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, //Логин которого я добавил
  `avatarUserFriend` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, //Аватар пользователя которого я добавил
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

А точнее мне надо сделать как в вк. Если пользователь добавлен показывать ему сообщение 
"вы уже его добавили", а если нет, то кнопку добавления (вы можете не писать кнопку, а просто текст, например "Добавить пользователя").

Я пробывал сделать так, но не работает:

```
$myid = $userinfo["id"]; //мой id
$yourid = $_GET[id]; //id страницы на которой я нахожусь
$result = mysql_query("SELECT idUserFriend FROM friends WHERE idUserFriend='$yourid'") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error()); //вывод из базы

    if ($result == $yourid) {
echo "Не добавить";
    } else {
    echo "Добавить";
    } //скрипт проверки
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте внимательно документацию, что возвращает mysql_query, посмотрите примеры использования...

`if ($result == $yourid)` так не проходит...

потому что, надо сделать что-то в таком ключе

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['idUserFriend'];
}
```

Comment: Просьба написать полный рабочий скрипт, т.к. я вас не понимаю, я только начал изучать php точнее даже не изучать, а просто писать функционал на php

Comment: Да и мне кстати нужен не вывод, а кое что другое. Вы вопрос хотя бы читали?

Comment: Вопрос я прочитал, но Вы мой ответ прочитали и поняли его???

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $tmp=$row['idUserFriend'];
}

if ($tmp == $yourid) 

и далеее

Comment: @cnofss Вам, уважаемый, такси или шашечки? Вы действительно думаете, что с таким нежеланием понять как это работает, удастся идти вперед?

Comment: @cnofss, если не понимаете, почитайте документацию.  
http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php  

Объясняю на пальцах:  
 \- mysql_query() возвращает дескриптор результата запроса (resource)

 \- $yourid у вас либо строка (string) либо целое число (int)  

resource == int (false)  
resource == string (false)